# Pandas pivot or groupby for dynamically generated columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with sales information in a supermarket. Each row in the dataframe represents an item, with several characteristics as columns. The original DataFrame is something like this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        my_data = [{'ticket_number' : '001', 'item' : 'tomato', 'ticket_price' : '21'},
               {'ticket_number' : '001', 'item' : 'candy', 'ticket_price' : '21'},
               {'ticket_number' : '001', 'item' : 'soup', 'ticket_price' : '21'},
               {'ticket_number' : '002', 'item' : 'soup', 'ticket_price' : '12'},
               {'ticket_number' : '002', 'item' : 'cola', 'ticket_price' : '12'},
               {'ticket_number' : '003', 'item' : 'beef', 'ticket_price' : '56'},
               {'ticket_number' : '003', 'item' : 'tomato', 'ticket_price' : '56'},
               {'ticket_number' : '003', 'item' : 'pork', 'ticket_price' : '56'}]
        df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)

In [2]: df
Out [2]:    
            ticket_number   ticket_price        item
         0        001            21           tomato
         1        001            21           candy
         2        001            21           soup
         3        002            12           soup
         4        002            12           cola
         5        003            56           beef
         6        003            56           tomato
         7        003            56           pork
```

I need a DataFrame where each row represents a ticket with all the items bought and the ticket price as columns. In this example:

```
            ticket_number   ticket_price      item1  item2  item3
         0        001            21           tomato candy  soup
         1        002            12           soup   cola
         2        003            56           beef   tomato pork
```

I tried using `df.groupby(ticket_number).item.value_counts()`, but that does not create new columns. I have never used `pivot_table`, maybe it is useful.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is known as **converting (your dataframe) from wide-form to long-form**. Using those keywords is going to get much better answers than the current title.

Comment: It's not even strictly a pivot-table since you're not aggregating counts (esp. for multiple entries, e.g. multiple 'candy') into a final table of counts, i.e. individual columns for 'candy','cola',.... Do you want the items unsorted (i.e. in order of occurrence or purchase), or sorted (e.g. alphabetically?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible way to use groupby to make lists of it that can then be turned into columns:

```
In [24]: res = df.groupby(['ticket_number', 'ticket_price'])['item'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series)

In [25]: res
Out[25]:
                                 0       1     2
ticket_number ticket_price
001           21            tomato   candy  soup
002           12              soup    cola   NaN
003           56              beef  tomato  pork
```

Then, after cleaning up this result a bit:

```
In [27]: res.columns = ['item' + str(i + 1) for i in res.columns]

In [29]: res.reset_index()
Out[29]:
  ticket_number ticket_price   item1   item2 item3
0           001           21  tomato   candy  soup
1           002           12    soup    cola   NaN
2           003           56    beef  tomato  pork
```

---

Another possible way to create a new column which numbers the items in each group with `groupby.cumcount`:

```
In [38]: df['item_number'] = df.groupby('ticket_number').cumcount()

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
     item ticket_number ticket_price  item_number
0  tomato           001           21            0
1   candy           001           21            1
2    soup           001           21            2
3    soup           002           12            0
4    cola           002           12            1
5    beef           003           56            0
6  tomato           003           56            1
7    pork           003           56            2
```

And then do some reshaping:

```
In [40]: df.set_index(['ticket_number', 'ticket_price', 'item_number']).unstack(-1)
Out[40]:
                              item
item_number                      0       1     2
ticket_number ticket_price
001           21            tomato   candy  soup
002           12              soup    cola   NaN
003           56              beef  tomato  pork
```

From here, with some cleaning of the columns names, you can achieve the same as above.

The reshaping step with `set_index` and `untack` could also be done with `pivot_table`: `df.pivot_table(columns=['item_number'], index=['ticket_number', 'ticket
_price'], values='item', aggfunc='first')`